# Send multiple variables to Node.js server with JQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

When I try to log the data that was received by the server it is displayed as one long string. Instead I would like the received data to be seperable as different variables.

**Client code**

```
function sendData() {

var datas = { testdata: "TEST", testdata2: "TEST2" };

$.ajax({
url: 'server',
data: JSON.stringify(datas),
type: 'POST', 

success: function (data) {

    $('#lblResponse').html(data);
},
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
    $('#lblResponse').html('Error connecting to the server.');
}
});

}
```

**Server code**

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    console.log('Request received');

    res.writeHead(200, { 
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('GOT DATA!');

        var receivedData = JSON.parse(chunk);

        console.log(receivedData);
    });

    res.end("hello");

}).listen(1337);
```

I would like to be able to call for a single variable to get the value from it in the server. For example console.log(testdata); should display the value "TEST".

Answer (score 0):

By stringifying your data object, you're sending a string to the server as the request body, and it's probably encoded using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" encoding.

1. You probably shouldn't `JSON.stringify(datas)`, just use `datas`.
2. You need to parse the request body on the server. For that you could use a module like [body](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body?__hstc=72727564.8a897a4b21b09fa018e6f3ae8a63a2c4.1419159105761.1438260200425.1439104796936.23&__hssc=72727564.2.1439104796936&__hsfp=2940474510#readme)